# Зациклить выборку из БД

Tags: php, циклы, while

Есть `ID` категории, например `233`, у него есть дочерняя категория, скажем `232`, а у `232` дочерняя категория `0` (то есть нет родителя).

Помогите написать функцию, которая будет делать выборку, и которая сложит всё в одну переменную. Писал

```
while ($result[0]->category_parent_id != 0) {
    var_dump(self::getAlias($dbConnect, $result[0]->category_id));
}
```

Но у меня в бесконечный цикл входит.

Как правильно написать?

Comment: ну так в цикле что-то обновлять надо... а-то он у вас постоянно `$result[0]` и проверяет, который не меняется... а должен

Comment: Я это понимаю только как ему сказать что вот тебе начальная категория остальные подставляй сюда.... Проста если писать что туда скидывать переменные которые возвращаются как ему выкинуть начальную тогда....

Comment: пробывал написать         while ($result[0]->category_parent_id != 0) {
            $self = self::getAlias($dbConnect, $self[0]->category_id);
            if (empty($self)) {
                var_dump(self::getAlias($dbConnect, $self[0]->category_id));
            } else {
                var_dump(self::getAlias($dbConnect, $result[0]->category_id));
            }
        }
В чём ошибка?

Comment: даже тут Вы все равно `$result[0]` не меняете, следовательно `while()` у Вас все время будет проверять одно и то же значение... поэтому всегда `true`, поэтому бесконечный цикл.

Comment: что такое `$result` и откда оно берется? Вам нужно в какой-то переменной иметь все категории, чтобы по ним пройтись. Выясните, где они, и уже по ним надо ставить цикл

Comment: $result ID искохдной категории
$self возращяет ID дочерних.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще раз - Вам надо каждый раз менять сожержимое `$result[0]`.

Вот такой вариант Вам может подойти.

```
$categories = Array(); // в этом массиве будем хранить категории
$categories[] = $result[0]->category_id; // заносим текущую категорию в массив
while ($result[0]->category_parent_id != 0) {
    $categories[] = $result[0]->category_parent_id; // заносим в массив родительскую категорию
    // далее, вытаскиваем из базы содержимое родительской категории 
    // фактически, это чуть измененое содержание Вашей функции getAlias();
    $queryCat = "SELECT * from __jshopping_categories where category_id = " . $result[0]->category_parent_id;
    $db->setQuery($queryCat);
    $result[0] = $db->loadObjectList(); // заносим в $result[0] данные о родительской категори, чтобы в следующем цикле использовались новые данные
}
```

В конце имеем массив `$categories` с `id` категорий в Вашей ветке.

Код писал "вслепую", так что Вам может его придется подправить.

Comment: Спасибо то что надо.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы решить эту задачу, надо перестать путаться в родственных отношениях. "дочерняя категория 0 (то есть нет родителя)" звучит довольно странно. Если нет родителя, то, наверное, *родительская* категория 0. Вот родительские категории и надо выбирать.

Помочь написать функцию невозможно по двум причинами. Во-первых, здесь не сервис по написанию кода. Во-вторых, никто не знает, что такое функция getAlias.

Comment: Не я такое придумал а jshopping. Я всего лишь оплакиваюсь от того что имею....
И вся моя проблема в том что я не могу понять как зациклить цикл то того пока категория в $self не будет равна тому самому 0...

Comment: 1) тогда наведите как написать мне данное.
2) getAlias эта дочерная функция в классе которая выберает категорию с переданным ID
Всё что в ней находится 
        $db = JDatabaseDriver::getInstance($option);
        $queryCat = "SELECT * from #__jshopping_categories where category_id = $catID";
        $db->setQuery($queryCat);
        return $db->loadObjectList();